# Подсказки в PhpStorm при наборе кода Emmet

Tags: phpstorm

В Visual Studio Code при наборе кода Emmet показываются подсказки классов Bootstrap
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В PhpStorm таких подсказок у меня нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли в PhpStorm настроить подсказки таким же образом?

Answer (score 0):

В Phpstorm таких подсказок для Emmet нет, вам нужно набрать аббревиатуру и нажать Tab. Тогда аббревиатура развернется в код.

Как вариант, вы можете с помощью Emmet создать div, а потом добавить класс с помощью обычных подсказок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это то понятно. Так я и делаю. Но хотелось бы как в VS Code. 
P.S. Т.е. дальше гуглить нет смысла?

Comment: Да, просто в Phpstorm это нормальное поведение Emmet, так он работал всегда, а для VSCode, наверное, придумали подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

Этой фичи в PHPStorm нет, проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-397](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-397)

Comment: Проголосовал...